# CCNA static IPv6 interface id understanding question

Tags: networking

[image]

Hello,

Can anyone advise why I would add ::1 to a subnet in IPv6? In this case I am looking to use the global unicast address and not the link-local even though I would normally do this.I would add the 1 to avoid setting the subnet id as the interface id is that correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). IPv6 does not have a subnet ID or broadcast address the way IPv4 does because IPv6 does not have the concept of broadcast. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/68259/8499) about that.

Comment: The text was part of the image and its my first post. A very detailed response and it has answered my question. Thanks.